# Backbone code produces unusable stack traces

Tags: backbone.js, javascript, javascript-framework, backbone-relational

Im working with a relatively large backbone codebase, and it seems like whenever I get a javascript error, no matter what it is. The stacktrace that appears in the console looks identical (example below). All of my models/views are created via the backbone .extend method.  Does anyone else have this problem, or know how to fix it?? I ususally have to put console.log statements everywhere to find the source of the error and its very time consuming. Thanks.

```
jquery-1.5.min.js:16       Uncaught InvalidConstructorArgs
   d.extend._Deferred.f.resolveWith     jquery-1.5.min.js:16
   v                                    jquery-1.5.min.js:16
  d.support.ajax.d.ajaxTransport.send.c jquery-1.5.min.js:16
```

Comment: Is this on JS runtime errors, or on syntax errors or the like? Also, what console are you using?

Comment: This is chrome, and runtime errors. Like uncaught exception, undefined reference, I even wrote an infinite recursive function by accident, and I got a stackoverflow. It had the same stack trace. My code should never be using jquery

Answer (score 5):

You should use an un-minified version of jQuery, Underscore and Backbone when debugging.  Life will be a lot easier if you do it that way.

As far as I can tell, you are having a problem with your `$.ajax` call within they `Backbone.sync` function, but it is way too difficult to tell when you are working with minified JS.

Comment: No its not in the sync. Its ANY javascript error. Like undefined reference for example, it doesnt matter where it is either

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Jquery 1.6.4 solved this problem